# How to center my navigation using .css

Tags: css, navigation

Good day
I am trying to center my naviation menu on my website, can someone help?

I know how to change colors and stuff, but never centered a navigation before

thanks

Code below:

```
/* Navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#topnav {
clear: left;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

#topnav ul {
list-style: none;
float: left;
}

#topnav ul li {
list-style: none;
float: left;
padding: 0 2px 0 0;
}

#topnav a {
float: left;
display: block;
color: #FFFFFF;
background: #00B0F0;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: "Actor", "Myriad Pro", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding: 10px 15px 11px;
font-size: 15px;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
line-height: 1;
}

#topnav li#active a,
#topnav a:hover {
color: #FFFFFF;
background: #00B0F0;
border: 0;
}
```

This is the HTML code related to navigation:

```
function initFlyouts(){initPublishedFlyoutMenus([{"id":"609790714960572849","title":"Home","url":"index.html"},{"id":"853266533690851204","title":"About us","url":"about-us.html"},{"id":"809862556966585268","title":"Pricing","url":"pricing.html"},{"id":"201576304336620950","title":"&#1593;&#1585;&#1576;&#1610;","url":"1593158515761610.html"}],'609790714960572849',"<li class='wsite-nav-more'><a href='#'>more...<\/a><\/li>",'active',false)}
```

and

```
<div id="topnav">
            <ul><li id='active'><a href='/index.html'>Home</a></li><li id='pg853266533690851204'><a href='/about-us.html'>About us</a></li><li id='pg809862556966585268'><a href='/pricing.html'>Pricing</a></li><li id='pg201576304336620950'><a href='/1593158515761610.html'>&#1593;&#1585;&#1576;&#1610;</a></li></ul>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Give your nav a fixed width and use `margin: auto`. That's all that can really be offered considering you've given very little detail

Comment: im using a website builder (weebly), i can post HTML but it will be too long, fine with you?

Comment: Why don't you create a jsFiddle, that might be of help if you have large code.

Comment: jsfiddle doesnt work here at the office, take forever to load:( thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a revised version of your code with the menu centered horizontally (no widths required):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
#topnav {
clear: left;
margin: 0;
}

#topnav ul {
list-style: none;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
margin:0; padding:0;
}

#topnav ul li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0 2px 0 0;
}

#topnav a {
float: left;
display: block;
color: #FFFFFF;
background: #00B0F0;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: "Actor", "Myriad Pro", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding: 10px 15px 11px;
font-size: 15px;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
line-height: 1;
}

#topnav li#active a,
#topnav a:hover {
color: #FFFFFF;
background: #00B0F0;
border: 0;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="topnav">
    <ul>
        <li id='active'><a href='/index.html'>Home</a></li><li id='pg853266533690851204'><a href='/about-us.html'>About us</a></li><li id='pg809862556966585268'><a href='/pricing.html'>Pricing</a></li><li id='pg201576304336620950'><a href='/1593158515761610.html'>&#1593;&#1585;&#1576;&#1610;</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi ralph, thanks but this code put them under each other, also on the left of the screen...looks like its not as simple as i may have though lol

Comment: It centers the menu nicely for me at the top middle of screen. What browser are you viewing the code in?

Comment: IE8, but i doubt the browser has an issue...let me try again incase i missed something

Comment: Works fine in IE8 for me. To test it, create a .html file and paste the code above into that, then open it in IE8.

Comment: you're absolutely right, it works in PLain HTML...I will contact weebly to check the reason

Comment: You're welcome. :-) There is probably some other code on the Weebly page getting in the way, so feel free to post a link to that and it shouldn't be too hard to see what's affecting the layout.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use fixed width in your menu, and want IE7 support, you can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/7K74B/1/

**Steps to achieve this behaviour**

1. Delete all `float:left;` references in your css (to prevent content float to left - no centering)
2. Delete the `display:block;` from `<a>` tags (to prevent tags take 100% width).
3. Set `display:inline;` to `<li>` tags (to put them side by side).
4. Set `text-align:center;` to `<ul>` to finally center your menu!

Hope this helps!

Note: In case you use this solution: because you have deleted all `float` references, you could also delete this markup: `<div style="clear:both"></div>`, because there's no float elements to clear.

Comment: no luck...maybe it has something to do with my provider "weebly.com"

Comment: @nadz So strange... all the answers we send you works for us, if nothing works for you, I think our answers are useless. I suggest you to test our solutions in other machines, and find the main error that is why standard css properties don't work as expected in your machine (or website), to help future users with same question as yours, and not make your own question too localized ;)

Comment: i agree, i think something is wrong from my provider's end. i am using weebly.com and its not easy to edit the html and CSS with them. Thank you guys i really appreciate the effort. for now i will contact their support to see what is happening

Comment: @nadz If you test it in various machines with still no luck, probably the issue is caused by Weebly. I found this page with [Weebly limitations](http://weeblyforums.com/2011/08/limitations-of-weebly/), but I'm not sure if any of these applied your case....

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Keep in mind as the others were saying in your comments that without seeing the HTML we have no idea whether this is what is needed.

```
/* Navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#topnav {
clear: left;
margin: auto 0;
overflow: hidden;
width: 400px; /*Define your own width here*/
}
```

Comment: thanks but nothing happened...maybe the HTML i added would help?

Comment: It does help a lot! You have a great answer above by @Arkana

Answer (score 0):

centered vertically or horizontaly? if horizontaly then the second answer on this post is usefull. If vertically then use something like :

```
li a {
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align:center;
 display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its horizontal but it stays the same even after adding the "margin:auto" part

Comment: you need to set a fixed width on the nav also for it to center in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code,

```
#topnav ul {
    list-style: none;
    /*Removed Float*/
}

#topnav {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Hope it will help